# React-native-image-picker (customButtons)

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I'd like to change the customButtons text color, anyone knows how to do it?

```
  var options = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  customButtons: [
    {name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook'},
  ],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images'
  }
};
```

e.g the standard color is black and I'd like to change it to blue in the title: 'Choose Phot from Facebook'.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: check the code of React-native-image-picker https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/master/index.js. I think you need to fork the library and make changes

Comment: any idea where in the library?